# How to split a string if the delimiter is one or more spaces?

Tags: c#, string, loops, if-statement

I'm trying to get this to write every word from input in a new line, even if there are more spaces between words, but I can't figure out what is wrong with this.

```
string phrase = Console.ReadLine();
string currentWord = ""; 

for (int i = 0; i < phrase.Length; i++)
{
if (phrase[i] == ' ') 
    Console.WriteLine(currentWord);
currentWord = "";
while (phrase[i] == ' ') 
    i++; 
if (phrase[i] != ' ') 
    currentWord += phrase[i];
}
Console.WriteLine(currentWord);
```

I'm only getting the last letter from every word. Any help, please?

And if let's say, I want to print out the nth word of phrase(n is from input), how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are not using braces in your `if` statement, this code gets executed in every iteration:

```
currentWord = "";
```

So you reset the value of `currentWord`.

You could simply use `Split` method with `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`, no need to reinvent the wheel:

```
var words = phrase.Split(new [] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: That wouldn’t really be much of an issue if the while loop was right. The real bug is the missing braces in the inner loop.

Comment: @Eva the way to avoid problems like this is to _always_ put the brackets

Comment: The only "good" reason to not use braces is if you have an `if` statement that is **incredibly** simple and brief (but still, use them). Whitespace is also your friend. This would have been a lot more obvious if you had an empty line here or there in your code. What you have now sort of blends together and becomes somewhat hard to read. Better indentation practices would have helped as well.

Answer (score 1):

Thats what happens when you don’t use curly braces in `if` and `while` bodies...

Write them both with braces and spot the difference with your current code.

Comment: Whitespace and proper indentation wouldn't hurt either. Makes it harder to decipher with everything crammed together and almost all at the same level of indentation.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do it this way..

First add this reference:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Then you can use a simple regex to split your string into words and a foreach loop to display the words:

```
var phrase = Console.ReadLine();
var words = Regex.Split(phrase, @"\s+");

foreach(var word in words)
    Console.WriteLine(word)
```

This is also a lot cleaner compared to the code you have, which makes it a lot easier to read, understand and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace char with `Replace` method

Follow code:

```
Console.ReadLine().Replace(" ","");
```